# PHP Singleton Acting Funny

Tags: php, class, object, singleton

I have the following code:

```
$e1 = call_user_func(array("MySQL_Extension", "getInstance"));
$e2 = call_user_func(array("Error_Extension", "getInstance"));
self::$extensions->MySQL = $e1;
self::$extensions->Error = $e2;

// Debug
echo "<pre>";
print_r(self::$extensions);
```

Each getInstance() method looks like this:

```
public static function getInstance()
{
    if (self::$_instance == null)
    {
        self::$_instance = new self;
    }

    return self::$_instance;
}
```

Both classes extend the same "Extension_Abstract" class, but for some reason, the "print_r" debug statement listed outputs the following:

```
stdClass Object (
    [MySQL] => MySQL_Extension Object
    [Error] => MySQL_Extension Object
)
```

Do you all have any idea why it would be returning two "MySQL_Extension" objects, and completely ignoring the Error_Extension class?  I'm so confused!

Comment: Is the `getInstance` method in the `MySQL_Extension` class or in both?

Answer (score 2):

See http://socket7.net/article/php-5-static-and-inheritance.

The problem is there is only one static variable, defined within the scope of the parent class. To create two static variables, the easiest way is to just define $_instance variable and get_instance method in both subclasses.

Another possible workaround is listed in the comments of the above article: "pass an extra class name parameter into the static method calls telling the method which class it should 'act as.'"

Comment: Yup!  Figured this out as soon as I posted it :P  Thanks for the help.  I'm trying to make this 5.2.x friendly so a lot of the better-laid-out singleton patterns are a no-go.

Answer (score 1):

Since `self` is resolving to `MySQL_Extension`, I'm assuming that each class has this method (rather than being defined in `Extension_Abstract`.  However, where is `self::$_instance` defined?  My instinct is that it's defined on `Extension_Abstract`.  Simply re-define it in each class (`protected static $_instance = null;`).

Also, instead of `self`, if you're using 5.3+ you should use `static` since it enables you to inherit and use late-static-binding to determine the class.

If that doesn't help, post more code (the class definitions would help)...

Answer (score 0):

Is `$_instance` in the base class?

If so, then you've got a singleton for the entire hierarchy, not each specific subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Try not using `self::`, but `MySQL_Extension::` and `Error_Extension::` explicitly.

Also, the abstract parent class `Extension_Abstract` should not contain the implementation for the `getInstance` method.

Answer (score 0):

late binding issue.

```
public static function getInstance()
{
    if (static::$_instance == null)
    {
        static::$_instance = new static();
    }

    return static::$_instance;
}
```